# Regarding never setting MacBook to sleep

Tags: battery

If I always keep my Macbook turned on, and never set it to sleep.

Plus, I keep a charger plugged into it whenever I use it, so the battery is always at 100%.

Will it be a problem?

Comment: What model MacBook?

Comment: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite right to be concerned about battery life when your MacBook is permanently plugged in - it is not good for a battery to always be at 100%. But, for recent Intel MacBooks, Apple provides some assistance for use cases like yours so that the battery is in fact not at 100% all the time.

[Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211094) says (slightly paraphrased):

"Battery Health Management" functionality is on by default after you upgrade to macOS 10.15.5 or later on a Mac notebook with Thunderbolt 3 ports.

To check that it is enabled follow these steps:

1. Choose System Preferences from the Apple menu , then click Battery.
2. Click Battery in the sidebar, then click Battery Health.

Make sure that "Manage battery longevity" is selected.